# Правильный порядок массива в php

Tags: php, массивы

Нужно построить массив с определенным порядком.
Я беру из базы пользователя и вытаскиваю его прямых потомков, потом надо вытащить потомков его потомков и так далее.

Структура одного пользователя такая :
id пользователя
id родителя

Надо засунуть id всех пользователей в один массив, но так, чтобы потомки шли сразу за родителями.
Буду благодарен если поможете

Comment: Как вы собираетесь различать какой родитель какой обычный?

Comment: поищите в сторону алгоритмов работы  с деревьями